# I have coded this low-level ai that guesses the users inputted number. How can I implement and improve this to make it high-level ai?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For my NEA project, I'm trying to code AI in Python 3, so I've tried some basic AI games. How can I improve this to make it high-level AI?

Basic AI game that guesses user input number. The computer has 10 attempts.

```
import random
userGuess = int(input("Enter a number between 0 and 100 for me to guess: "))
compGuess = 0
lorange = 0
hirange = 100
compAttempts = 0
while compAttempts < 10:
  compGuess = random.randint(lorange, hirange)
  if compGuess == userGuess:
    print(compGuess,"I win!")
    compAttempts = 10
  elif compGuess > userGuess:
    print(compGuess,"is too high ")
    hirange = compGuess
    compAttempts = compAttempts + 1
  elif compGuess < userGuess:
    print(compGuess,"is too low ")
    lorange = compGuess
    compAttempts = compAttempts + 1
```

This works and there don't seem to be any errors that I can see.

Comment: Why do you want to fix it if it's not broken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly speaking, your code isn't AI. AI would be something that learns from it's past, however you're simply generating a random number and checking if it's equal, smaller or bigger than the user input.

What you've coded is a variant of binary search. In worst case scenario your code will take O(n) guesses, for e.g when user's input is 100 and random returns 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ...

You could improve your code to be true binary search for O(log n) performance (you can easily look this up on Google). Basically instead of:

```py
compGuess = random.randint(lorange, hirange)
```

do:

```py
compGuess = (lorange + hirange)/2
```

This isn't AI and but even in the worst case it will only take max 7 tries to guess your number.

I'm not sure how AI or ML would be helpful in this particular case. If it was something like guess next number in series or such, you could've surely used ML.

Also, this is something you would want to post in code review stack exchange.

Comment: ok, thanks. sorry, I'm still new at this.